# Getting HRESULT: 0x800A01B6 Exception while getting elements from InternetExplorerMedium website

Tags: vb.net, vba, hresult

I'm trying to make some code on VB.net that opens a website and logs in, and after that runs a report.  Everything has been working fine when I try to get any of the from the website, but the ones that have this instruction within the OnClick property = "return oamSubmitForm('inputParamView:paramForm','inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106');"

Basically, if you see the following code, you see that I click on some of the CheckBoxes and it works just fine, but when I retrieve the button, it doesn't type an input, it actually has the link of the website when I use a whatc while debugging.

This is my code (I skipped the login section):

```
Private Sub open Page()
ieb = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium()
ieb.Navigate("http://example.example/qptheme2/pages/index.faces")
ieb.visible = True
ieb.Silent = True

While Not (ieb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    Application.DoEvents()
End While

If v.checked = False Then
    v.Click()
End If

v = ie.Document.GetElementById("inputParamView:paramForm:inputParametertuesday")

If v.checked = False Then
    v.Click()
End If

v = ie.Document.GetElementById("inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106")

v.Click() '<-- IT FAILS HERE Exception HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
```

If I check the watch it shows mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass {http://example.example/qpreport/savedpages/savedReports.faces#}
if I check the source code from the page, this is the element that I'm trying to get:

```
<a id="inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106" onclick="return
oamSubmitForm('inputParamView:paramForm','inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106');" href="#"
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with the property OnClick.

I will appreciate any of your help trying to solve this issue.

Comment: "but the ones that have this instruction..." do what? Is that sentence incomplete? Also, please fix your code formatting. You can use backticks instead of double quotes for inline code, and all other code should have four spaces at the start of the line to put it in a proper code block.

Comment: does the next line gives you the answer?
the instruction is "return oamSubmitForm('inputParamView:paramForm','inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106');"
im having a hard time trying to format stuff here sorry

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by myself. I just had to instance the element I was retrieving as mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass
after that, I was able to click on it.

```
Dim l As mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass = ieb.Document.GetElementById("inputParamView:paramForm:_idJsp106")
l.click()
```